# Online resize logicaldrive on Smart Array P410i

Tags: debian, hp, debian-squeeze, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

On my HP Proliant server I have hot added 2 extra drives. To expand the current raid 1 array I used the following commands:

```
hpacucli ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 modify raid=1+0
hpacucli ctrl slot=0 ld 1 add drives=allunassigned
```

Now the logicaldrive looks like this:

```
# hpacucli ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 show

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

array A

  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 136.7 GB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1+0
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 35132
     Strip Size: 256 KB
     Status: OK
     Array Accelerator: Enabled
     Unique Identifier: **************************
     Disk Name: /dev/sda
     Mount Points: /boot 511 MB
     Logical Drive Label: **************************
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

Now the size is this 136.7 GB, so I tried the following command, but got a warning:

```
# hpacucli ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 modify size=max

Warning: Extension may not be supported on certain operating systems.
     Performing extension on these operating systems can cause data to
     become inaccessible. See ACU documentation for details. Continue?

     (y/n)
```

I'm wondering what could happen if I say yes and if it's save to do this on a running installation.

Details: 64 bit debian squeeze (proxmox VE 2) with kernel 2.6.32-16-pve.

Comment: Did you run the expansion?

Comment: Yes, and it worked exactly as ewwhite said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're okay to say yes.

However, your disk sizes aren't consistent. Did you add 300GB to a 146GB mirror pair? If so, you'll only get ~288GB usable following logicaldrive expansion.

Would you have been better off creating a new logical drive of the 300GB pair, and being able to leverage the full capacity of those drives?

Comment: I ordered 146G drives, but since they did not have them in stock I got 300G drives with a 146G label. Doesn't it create 2 mirror groups with 2 different sizes?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have them in a single logicaldrive, so if you wish to have four disks in the same array, the array will treat the 300GB disks as if they were 146GB. Of course, you could also replace the original disks with 300GB and end up with a 600GB usable array.