# How to move RAID 1 to RAID 1+0

Tags: raid, hp, raid1, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have two HP disks in RAID 1 (300 Gb), and would like to at 2 additional disks in RAID 1+0 having in total of 600 Gb on C:.

I would like to know is it possible to do it using Array Configuration Utility without loosing and data?

Controller is Smart Array P410i 512Mb.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the HP Array Configuration Utility. The term you're interested in is "Array Transformation". [See page #16 of the manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf).

- Add the physical drives.
- Expand the array.
- At that point, you'll either want to add a new logical drive or expand the existing.
- If you expand the existing, you may require downtime since it's your C: drive.

[HP even has a video detailing this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-SRXLcIH6Y)..

Other relevant questions here:

[Online resize logicaldrive on Smart Array P410i](https://serverfault.com/questions/468882/online-resize-logicaldrive-on-smart-array-p410i)

[RAID5 on SmartArray P410i online resize](https://serverfault.com/questions/374349/raid5-on-smartarray-p410i-online-resize/374357#374357)

[Can I convert a 1 disk RAID 0 to RAID 1?](https://serverfault.com/questions/329735/can-i-convert-a-1-disk-raid-0-to-raid-1/335058#335058)

Comment: great info. I would like to have it all on one logical drive. Is there a recommended solution, or having RAID10 with 4 disks on one logical drive is acceptable solution?

Comment: It's a fine solution, but depending on your OS, you'll need to resize the actual C: partition offline once you're done with the HP tasks.

Comment: I am on SBS2011, what do you mean by resizing C partition offline?

Comment: @John You need to grow your C: filesystem to take advantage of the new space. That's beyond the scope of this question, though.

Comment: can you share a link so I can read some more on that topic?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to do it using Array Configuration Utility without
>   losing and data?

You don't mention which specific SmartArray controller you have but on all recent models online-RAID-migration is possible and safe, but slow.

Comment: sorry, controller is Smart Array P410i 512Mb

Comment: Ok, well with that model you need either a battery backing for the cache (which I assume you have as part of the 512MB cache thing) or Flash-based cache - which again you may have. If you have either you can do migrations live :) You're going to want to know how next aren't you? If so I'd need to know what OS you're running first.

Comment: I am on SBS2011 but ewwite provided very detailed explanation