# Disk Space increase in HP Proliant DL 360 Gen8

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a HP Proliant DL 360 Gen8 server with 8X 146GB drives:

- Array #1–#3 HDD as Raid 1  (2 HDD mirrored with 1 HDD as hot backup)
- Array #2 – 5 HDD as Raid 10/1+0/0+1 (4 HDD mirrored/striped with 1HDD as hot backup).

I need at least 2TB of additional usable space.

Can I upgrade the 5 disks in array #2 one at a time then allocate the new space into Array #2?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Mitch

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Are you having a problem with the process or just wondering about the functionality of a Smart Array RAID controller?

Please see: [How to move RAID 1 to RAID 1+0](https://serverfault.com/questions/545809/how-to-move-raid-1-to-raid-10/545833#545833)

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to assist me. I am wondering about the functionality. I am fairly new to the disk management arena. I currently have both arrays above in place. What I think I am learning is that I can purchase 5 new larger SAS HDD's with the same speed as the existing drives (10,000 RPM) and swap them out 1 at a time with the five drives in Array #2. Once complete I can utilize the Smart Array RAID controller to allocate the new space into Array #2. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I am reading the documentation that you provided now, thanks.